# In what order and how exactly the CSS classes are applied?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<p class="text-uppercase">1 Example Text</p>
<p class="text-lowercase">2 Example Text</p>
<p class="text-capitalize">3 example text</p>
<p class="text-capitalize text-lowercase">4 EXAMPLE TEXT</p>
<p class="text-lowercase text-capitalize">5 EXAMPLE TEXT</p>
```

CSS:

```
.text-lowercase {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text-capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Output:

```
1 Example Text

2 Example Text

3 example text

4 EXAmPLE TExT

5 EXAmPLE TExT
```

I expected #4 and #5 to be

```
example text - first capitalize, then lowercase
Example Text - first lowercase, then capitalize
```

What's going on exactly?

Demo: http://codepen.io/sanspace/pen/xwOQyL (colors added for clarity)

Related: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17672

**EDIT**:

Let me add my understanding. I thought when two transformations are applied:

`AbC` becomes `abc` on applying `lowercase` and then
`abc` becomes `Abc` on applying `capitalize`

However, it seems like

`AbC` becomes `abc` on applying `lowercase` and then
the `capitalize` was applied to the original text. i.e.
on `AbC` not on `abc` as I thought.

Can some one shed some light on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSS rules are applied in order of the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order).

> Sort according to importance (normal or important)

None of your rules are `!important` so that has no influence.

> and origin (author, user, or user agent).

All of your rules come from the author stylesheet, so that has no influence.

> Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector

Since all your selectors consist of a single *class selector*, they have equal specificity, so that has no influence

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.

They are therefore applied in the order they appear in the stylesheet.

(The order the class names appear in the class attribute is entirely irrelevant.)

> AbC becomes abc on applying lowercase and then the capitalize was applied to the original text. i.e. on AbC not on abc as I thought.

The rule describes how the raw data should be presented. An overridden rule has no effect. It doesn't undergo multiple transformations.

Some properties allow multiple effects to be applied but they do that by accepting multiple values in a single rule (e.g. `text-decoration: underline overline`).

Comment: You mean, the class `text-lowercase` was applied?

I thought it was never applied in case of #4 and #5!!

Comment: It gets applied and then immediately overridden by `text-transform: capitalize;`.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain my understanding. I guess your comment confirms it. Is it applicable for all the styles? Each style is applied over the original element not the element modified by a previous style?

Comment: Only the second one is applied because it overrides the first one. The way you wrote it, it cannot be lowercase AND capitalize at the same time. Because of the order in your css file, the capitalize will always override the lowercase.

Comment: Due to cascading, anything lower on a stylesheet overrides anything before (higher than) it on that element.  As far as I can tell, there can only be one text-transform applied on to an element.

Comment: refer this link https://www.quora.com/In-what-order-are-CSS-classes-applied for more clearity